# Instruments crashed on startup using Appium with IOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, simulator

I have installed xcode, appium and ios simulator while im running code im getting below error please help me.

`error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup`

Comment: Im using simulator

Comment: Error: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)